# Multiple variables initialization in objective C

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, initialization, jbutton

I'm working on a project in objective C, and on another project in Java too. And i ask me a question, because i know how to make mulitple declaration in Java, like this :

```
for (int l = 7; l>0; l--)
    {
        for (int g = 1; g<8; g++)
        {
            ButtonTest = new JButton();
            ButtonTest.setBorderPainted(false);
            ButtonTest.setOpaque(true);
            ButtonTest.setName("Bouton"+l+g);
            ButtonTest.addActionListener(this);
            PanelTest.add(ButtonTest);
        }
    }
```

How can i make this sort of code in objective C, with UIButtons for example ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What do you want to do with the UIButtons after they're generated? Add them to a view?

Comment: Yes, and use is after =)

Comment: Note that you'll quickly fail miserably if you treat conversion from Java to Objective-C as a line-by-line exercise.  You really need to understand the underlying frameworks and design patterns.

Comment: I know that, i don't try to make basics conversions but understand how to do this sort of code in objective c ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as in Java:

```
for (int l = 7; l>0; l--)
{
    for (int g = 1; g<8; g++)
    {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        // Do any other configuration here.
        [button setTitle:@"foo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myView addSubview:button];
    }
}
```

This will generate UIButtons and add them to a view. You'll probably have to generate the coordinates and size yourself though, I don't know if that's different in Java.

Comment: Oh thanks guy, looks like working ! So equivalent as .setName would be in objective C .titlelabel.text and in your example, the name of the UIButton will be foo ?

Comment: `titleLabel.text` represents the text displayed on the button, if that's what you mean.

Comment: You should use the `UIButton setTitle:forState:` method to set the button's title. See the docs for `UIButton`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. Updated my answer to use `setTitle:forState:`.